# Change the URI on click

Tags: android, onclick, media-player, uri, buttonclick

I'm making a radio app, the app is kinda finished. But i want to let the user change the station by clicking the button specified for each station.

**UPDATE:** I put in more code.

So i was thinking about something like this? But I'm not sure where to put it.

```
public void onClickListener (View v) {
    if (v == rDuhok) {
        kRadio.setDataSource("http://87.106.215.231:9992");
    } else if (v == rVin) {
        kRadio.setDataSource("http://93.91.197.214:1234");
    }
}
```

Right now i have the link for the station where it says *MyURI*, and the app is working as expected. But I want to be able to change the URI by clicking a button.

```
public class KurdRadioActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;
private Button buttonPlay;
private Button buttonStopPlay;
private Button rDuhok;
private Button rVin;
private MediaPlayer kRadio;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();

} 

private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    rDuhok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rDuhok);
    rDuhok.setOnClickListener(this);

    rVin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rVin);
    rVin.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(50);
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {

    buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    kRadio.prepareAsync();

    kRadio.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            kRadio.start();

        }
    });
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (kRadio.isPlaying()) {
        kRadio.stop();
        kRadio.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {

    kRadio = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        kRadio.setDataSource("http://87.106.215.231:9992");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    kRadio.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        kRadio.stop();
    }
}
```

Just want to say that im new in programing and im just learning, thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an `onClick` listener. This is one of the most basic things you can do in Android... you can save yourself a lot of time by reading the developers site instead of asking here :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood thanks for commenting, i've been reading some and i was also thinking about onClickLisetener. I've updated with more code, i would be greatful if you cold look into it.

Comment: Your question says "the app works as expected" and it looks like when you click the button, you are changing the URI... so I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: no, the URI changing part isnt working. I haven't put it in, im not sure how to.. @AlexLockwood

Comment: How do you generate the buttons which the user clicks to change channel? Are the channel buttons predefined in xml or do you dynamically generate them in code?

Comment: @udiboy their predefined in xml.